# triggering a server error to test locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, try-catch

I want to test a catch in my code and want to know how i can trigger an error locally with this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOpen)
      setShowSuccessConfirmation(false);
  }, [isOpen]);

  const enableSubmission = currentDocuments.length > 0;

  const submitPanel = () => {
    const documentIds = currentDocuments.map(doc => doc.documentId);

    setIsSubmitting(true);

    TradingService.requestRenewal(panelState!.modelCode, documentIds)
      .then(() => {
        setShowSuccessConfirmation(true);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setShowErrorModal(true);
        setShowSuccessConfirmation(false);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsSubmitting(false);
      });
  };
```

Comment: check out [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) and [mock](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/#mock) the API call so that it rejects the promise to force the catch.